# Postfix to infix converter Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I am trying to make an RPN calculator program and want to have a label which shows the expression you entered. If you enter 3,5,4,+,/ the label would show ((4+5) / 3). I am having trouble implementing this. I am using a mutableArray I call stack which holds both numbers and operands. Another major problem is that the string passed wont be a full string rather it is passed everytime the user enters a value so the program must function continuously with only one item on the stack or two. Here is the code.

```
   + (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
NSMutableArray *stack;

if([NSArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    stack = [program mutableCopy];

NSUInteger count = [stack count];
NSString* symbol;
NSMutableString *result;
[result appendString:@"("];



for( NSUInteger i=0; i<count; i++){



    if ([[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"+"] || [[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"-"] ||  [[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"/"] ||  [[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"*"] ||  [[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"sin"] || [[stack lastObject] isEqualToString:@"cos"] )
        {
            symbol = [stack lastObject];
            [stack removeLastObject];

        }
    else
        {


            if( [stack lastObject] != nil){
                [result appendString:[stack lastObject]];
                [stack removeLastObject]; }


         // [result stringByAppendingString:symbol];


            if( [stack lastObject]){
            [result appendString:[stack lastObject]];
                [stack removeLastObject];}


            [result appendString:@")"];

            [stack addObject:result];
        }
}

return [stack lastObject];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

One major issue in your code is your use of `stringByAppendingString`: since `NSString` is *immutable*, the code should assign the result returned from the method to the original string, like this:

```
result = [result stringByAppendingString:[stack lastObject]];
```

When you need to concatenate multiple strings dynamically, a better approach is to use `NSMutableString`. This is a subclass of `NSString` which lets you append other strings like this:

```
[result appendString:[stack lastObject]];
```

You can avoid appending strings altogether by using the `stringWithFormat:` method.

Starting the stack with the content of the program is not the right thing to do either: you should go through the `program` symbols one by one, push numbers, and process operations by popping two last items, inserting the operation between the left and the right sides, adding parentheses around it, and pushing it back onto the stack.

```
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(NSArray*)program {
    NSArray *ops = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+",@"-",@"*",@"/",@"sin",@"cos",nil];
    NSMutableArray *stack = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *s in program) {
        if ([ops indexOfObject:s] != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *lhs = [stack lastObject];
            [stack removeLastObject];
            NSString *rhs = [stack lastObject];
            [stack removeLastObject];
            [stack addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@ %@)", lhs, s, rhs]];
        } else {
            [stack addObject:s];
        }
    }
    return [stack lastObject];
}
```

Comment: I changed the things above thanks for pointing it out, but the program is still not working

Comment: @TerrelGibson Could you update the question with the latest version of your program then?